# Android adding complex layout in ViewFlipper

Tags: android

I have complex view with more linearlayout-s  and relativelayout in one child in ViewFlipper.
I want to group this complex view in one child of ViewFlipper.

ViewFlipper separates my layout in more child

How can I add view with complex layout in one child ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a sigle parent layout for each "page" in the view flipper.  So you need to wrap your complex view in some other container layout.